# Is a continuous random variable equivalent to a random variable without point mass?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

According to the Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference (2nd edition) Figure 2.1.2, both (a) and (b) are cases of a continuous cdf. According to their definition(definition 1.5.7), both are continuous random variables.

This kind of surprises me because my initial visual impression for a continuous random variable is that it should be a variable that changes continuously on a connected support (like normal, exponential, beta distributions), but in fact the support of a continuous random variable needs not be connected, and could have gaps or jumps (see the red pdf I drew in this attached figure).

My question is then, what is a more direct definition or characterization of a continuous random variable (without refering to its cdf)? Is a continuous random variable the same as a random variable without point mass (no point in its support has strictly positive probability attached)?  Thanks!

Comment: In measure theoretic probabilty a continuous r.v. is defined as one without a point mass. But in elementary statistics books it is defined as a r.v. with a density function. Unfortunately there are different definitions which don't agree with each other.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

A continuous RV is one without point mass. This is equivalent to the continuity of the CDF because a CDF is right continuous and the mass of a point $x$ is equal to $F(x)-F(x-)$, and so this is zero if and only if $F$ is continuous as $x$.

There is a more precise notion of an absolutely continuous RV which is a RV with a density.

Finally, a comment on vocab. "Random Variable" is not the best fitting name. It is really a deterministic function (from the sample space to ${\mathbb R}$). All "randomness" is drawn from the choice of the probability distribution. For example consider the sample space  $\Omega= [0,1]$ (equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra), the function $X(\omega) = \omega$. If we equip the space with the Lebesgue measure, $X$ is uniform (absolutely continuous), and if we equip it with the delta measure at $\frac 12$, then $X$ is discrete: equal to $\frac12$ with probability $1$...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful!